# English idioms about inefficiency

Tags: idioms

Is it right to say about something inefficient, for example: 'This process is poorly organized. It's like one leg is running and another is walking?'

Comment: Nor sure about an idiom but it does sound like a cool analogy.

Comment: I'm guessing you got this idiom from Russian, because my grandma also uses it.

Comment: There is the idiom, "Two steps forward, one step back" to describe a tough experience trying to get a job done. This expression doesn't blame the person making the effort for the difficulty but it is more about the nature of the problem being difficult to make headway on.  Sometimes that is turned into 'one step forward two steps back', humorously to say that the harder you try the worse things get.

Comment: I'm not aware of this idiom in Russian however, I speak rus. It's just an analogy.

Comment: That gait trips past *inefficient* to fall at *downright dangerous*.

Answer (score 1):

That phrase is not a common idiom in English.  However, a similar idiom related to limbs exists and means something very similar:

> **the left hand doesn't know what the right hand is doing**

The idiom is defined per *Dictionary.com*:

> The actions are uncoordinated, especially when they are contrary, as in
>
> *Purchasing has placed the order and accounting says we can't pay for more supplies this month; the left hand doesn't know what the right hand is doing.*

It relates to the phrase you described above in that it makes a figurative description of inefficiency by pitting the one arm against the other, similar to "one leg is running and another is walking."